Git push sparse repository
I'm trying to customize a small part of a big repository, then have my customization pushed into a GitHub repository.
I've followed sparse cloning instructions to have the first stage done. Committed the necessary edits. But when I push to my repository, everything in the big repository gets pushed.
Is there a way to only push the small part?
Elaboration:
Big repo contains following directories:

sub1
sub2
sub3

subsub1



I'm interested in modifying and maintaining subsub1 folder. Therefore:

git clone --filter=blob:none --sparse  %your-git-repo-url%
cd %the repository directory%
git sparse-checkout add sub3/subsub1
cd sub3/subsub1

Having my commits over that directory contents, then:

git remote add myorigin %my-github-repo%
git push origin %branch%

Then the whole Big repo gets pushed, including sub1,sub2 directories.
Desired outcome that sub3/subsub1 directory gets pushed only. And preferably if I can find sub3 the root directory in myorigin repo.

What do you mean by "everything in the big repository gets pushed"? How do you know how much gets pushed?

All the files in the branch. Not shorted to the sparse part.

That's not really how sparse checkouts are meant to work. Maybe you're looking for subtree pushing?

(Note that a "sparse repository" isn't really a thing. What you have is a sparse checkout of a complete repository.)
